# Exposing data to BI and generating reports in neo4j

Tags: cypher, neo4jclient

What is the best practice  exposed data to BI from neo4j ? and If we are generating reports what is best practice to generate reports in Neo4j

Need your guidance on this

Answer (score 0):

This page: [Using PowerBI with Neo4j](http://xclave.co.uk/2017/06/22/using-powerbi-with-neo4j/) explains the setup of PowerBI - in essence you use the REST end point that Neo4j exposes and connect as a 'Web' connection in Power BI.

As to your second part of the question - that's your usage of PowerBI and isn't something that can really be answered here.